Telegram Login Widget not return callback after login
I am having some problems trying to make the Telegram Login Widget work on my website. The callback is never called after a successful login.
I'm using the Widget in a React app. Currently, I'm using the lib react-telegram-login.
const handleTelegramResponse = response => {    
    console.log("see response ", response)
};

<TelegramLoginButton dataOnauth={handleTelegramResponse} botName="myname_bot"/> 

I also tried a hard code version (the accepted one here is what I've done) so the lib would not be required, but the result is the same: no callback being called. This makes me think it might be a configuration mistake on the Telegram app...
My issue is that the callback handleTelegramResponse is never called.
Steps:
1 - using a Bot that already exists (also tried to create a new one... no effect).
2 - Set the domain to a temporary URL with Localtunnel - https url. This is the example of url "https://public-llamas-hide.loca.lt" that I am sending
3 - Open the url and the Telegram Login Button is presented.
4 - Click on the button, add my mobile phone number on the popup window and confirm on my telegram account.
5 - I was supposed to see the information from the user printed with the callback handleTelegramResponse.
I am lost here.

Did u find an answer?

no =/
I ended up stopping using telegram for now... But I plan to dive into this again as soon as possible.

i fixed it with Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups header

This may be due to the fact that Telegram Login Widget has a different origin (oauth.telegram.org). You need to allow this URL in your React CORS configuration.
You can check answers to this question on StackOverflow: How to allow CORS in react.js?
